# Upper bound for the expectation of a random function

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $M(\cdot)$ denote a real-valued random function on $\mathbb{R}$; i.e., $M(\theta)$ is a random variable for each (nonrandom) $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$. For a random variable $\hat{\theta}$ such that $\hat{\theta}\in[0,1]$ a.s., we want to derive an upper bound of $\mathbb{E}[|M(\hat{\theta})|]$. Can we always say that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[|M(\hat{\theta})|]\leq \sup_{\theta\in[0,1]}\mathbb{E}[|M(\theta)|]
\end{align}
is true? I suspect that this inequality is incorrect, but I couldn't find any counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an easier counter example: Let $X$ be random variable that is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. For $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, define
$$M(\theta) = \mathbb{1}_{\{X=\theta\}}.$$
We can then choose $\hat{\theta}=X$ and get
$$\mathbb{E}[|M(\hat{\theta})|] = 1$$
but
$$\sup_{\theta\in [0,1]} \mathbb{E}[|M(\theta)|] = 0$$
because for all $\theta\in[0,1]$ we have $M(\theta)=0$ almost surely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a counterexample.  Let $\ \hat{\theta}\ $ be uniformly distributed over $\ [0,1]\ $ and
$$
M(\theta)=1-\big(\hat{\theta}-\theta\big)^2\ .
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(|M(\hat{\theta})|\big)&=1\hspace{2em}\text{and}\\
\mathbb{E}\big(|M(\theta)|\big)&=1-\mathbb{E}\big(\big(\hat{\theta}-\theta\big)^2\big)\ .
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
\sup_{\theta\in[0,1]}\mathbb{E}\big(|M(\theta)|\big)&=1-\mathbb{Var}\big(\hat{\theta}\big)\\
&=\frac{11}{12}\\
&<\mathbb{E}\big(|M(\hat{\theta})|\big)\ .
\end{align}

Comment: I can see that $\ \mathbb{E}\big[|M(\hat{\theta})|\,\big|\,\hat{\theta}\,\big]\le\mathbb{E}\sup_\limits{\theta\in[0,1]} \big[|M(\theta)|\,\big]\ $ almost surely. Why is $\ \mathbb{E}\big[|M(\hat{\theta})|\,\big|\,\hat{\theta}\,\big]\le\sup_\limits{\theta\in[0,1]}\mathbb{E}\big[|M(\theta)|\,\big]\ $ almost surely?

Comment: Good question. It looks like I was inadvertently assuming  $\ M\ $ to be independent (as a random function) of the random variable $\ \hat{\theta}\ $.  Realising this led me to the counterexample I've now given.

Comment: Many thanks, Trailblazer and lonza leggiera for counter examples! Kavi's question is also very helpful as I made the same mistake.